# Same layout for multiple screen

Tags: android

My problem is when I am making differnt layouts for multiple screens such as layout-small, layout-normal etc. then most of the nexus mobile run only on layout-normal due to which in 4 inch mobile, my layout can't able to fit, for making it to fit I made layout-small but its working for layout-large not for layout-small.

layout-small

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.vishal.a4sa.SecondActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@drawable/tooth3">

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="CATEGORIES"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/categories"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

<br.com.bloder.magic.view.MagicButton
    android:id="@+id/instruments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:magic_button_size="100dp"
    app:button_icon="@drawable/tools2"
    app:button_icon_width="70dp"
    app:button_icon_height="60dp"
    app:hide_text="INSTRUMENTS"
    app:icon_button_color="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:expandable_area_color="#ff0008"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />

<br.com.bloder.magic.view.MagicButton
    android:id="@+id/material"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:magic_button_size="100dp"
    app:button_icon="@drawable/material"
    app:button_icon_width="80dp"
    app:button_icon_height="60dp"
    app:hide_text="MATERIALS"
    app:icon_button_color="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:expandable_area_color="#ff0008"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ABOUT US"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/aboutus" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout-normal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.vishal.a4sa.SecondActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@drawable/tooth3">

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="CATEGORIES"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/categories"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

<br.com.bloder.magic.view.MagicButton
    android:id="@+id/instruments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:magic_button_size="100dp"
    app:button_icon="@drawable/tools2"
    app:button_icon_width="70dp"
    app:button_icon_height="60dp"
    app:hide_text="INSTRUMENTS"
    app:icon_button_color="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:expandable_area_color="#ff0008"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />

<br.com.bloder.magic.view.MagicButton
    android:id="@+id/material"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:magic_button_size="100dp"
    app:button_icon="@drawable/material"
    app:button_icon_width="80dp"
    app:button_icon_height="60dp"
    app:hide_text="MATERIALS"
    app:icon_button_color="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:expandable_area_color="#ff0008"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ABOUT US"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/aboutus" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why are you making the different layout for small, normal screen? Read this https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html .

Comment: i dont get it,by making different layouts such as layout-small,layout large for same xml file,we can do

Comment: You need not to make different screen for small screen or bigs. According to Android documentation, set view width and height in such a way that you need not to make different layout for different screen. Only make different screen layout only in case of tablet and tab-landscape

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.